# Is there a fast way to switch System time zone from the command line?

Tags: macos, system-settings, timezone

I usually do it through the System Preference panel for Date & Time, but I'd like a quicker way to do this if there is one.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the following Terminal command:

```
sudo systemsetup -settimezone timezone
```

For a list of valid `timezone` values, use `sudo systemsetup -listtimezones`.

To get the current timezone, use:

```
sudo systemsetup -gettimezone
```

Comment: And just for the record, you can also *get* the current timezone by doing `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone`.

Comment: is there a way to get the timezone without root?

Comment: How can I update NTP source from CLI?

Comment: Sadly, this isn't working for me. It seems to change it (says `Set TimeZone: America/New_York` and returns exit code 0) but then `sudo systemsetup -gettimezone` returns the previous value (`Time Zone: America/Los_Angeles`).

Comment: To get timezone without sudo, use `date +"%Z %z"`. This displays something like `EDT -0400`, the upper case z outputs the TZ abbreviation, lowercase the UTC offset.

Answer (score -1):

Additionally:

**Printing a random timezone**:

```
ruby -e "puts `sudo systemsetup -listtimezones`.lines.sample.strip"
```

**Setting a random timezone**:

```
sudo systemsetup -settimezone (ruby -e "puts `sudo systemsetup -listtimezones`.lines.sample.strip")
```

**Finding a timezone** (e.g. containing "Los" in this case):

```
sudo printf ''; sudo systemsetup -listtimezones | grep Los
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this for the random timezone trick. Alas, it does not answer the question, and should probably be a comment instead of an answer. Cool script though!